# Range.text object required

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, text, cell

I'm having some issues while trying to modify Cell Text via Range command

Here you have the code. I'm creating a game with turn based gameplay. In a first function I initialize the different array. listecase is a 2 dimension array which define the list of all tray cases.
Each tray have different properties first I have the position in the cell sheet (for example listecase(0,0) = "F69" because the first tray case is located in the cell F69)

Using this method I need to use Range method to access text from tray case.

```
Dim listecase(40, 11) As Variant
Dim joueur() As Integer
Dim tour As Integer

Sub lancer()
Dim de1 As Integer
Dim de2 As Integer
Randomize
de1 = Int(Rnd * 7)
de2 = Int(Rnd * 7)

Range(listecase(joueur(tour), 0)).Replace tour, "", xlWhole
MsgBox Range(listecase(joueur(tour), 0)).Text

'Throw the error here
Range(listecase(joueur(tour), 0)).Text = Trim(Range(listecase(joueur(tour), 0)).Text)
joueur(tour) = joueur(tour) + de1 + de2

'And here
Range(listecase(joueur(tour), 0)).Text = Range(listecase(joueur(tour), 0)).Text & " " & tour
Call jeux
End sub
```

I'm going to explain a bit my code. This macro should simulate dice throwing. Then it should move the player position to the good tray case. The current tray case of players can be found in joueur() and tour is an id to identify which player should play.

What I'm trying to do is, when I throw the dice it delete automatically the player number in his tray case then it put his id in the new player's tray case.

Well I signed the line which throws error 424 Object required

I'm sorry if I'm not clear with my explanation and sorry for my bad English

Thank you

Comment: Range.Text is not appropriate. Use Range. Value or Range.Value2 instead

Comment: @MacroMarc Thank you, in fact with Range.Value it does excatly what I want to do.